# R/rgl - Strange errors when using rect3Drgl

Tags: r, rgl

I have a strange behavior when using `rect3Drgl()`.  Here's my script:

```
library(rgl)
library(plot3Drgl)

uvw = matrix(c(1,-1,0,  0,0,1,  0,1,-1), ncol=3)

plot3d(uvw, xlab="", ylab="", zlab="", xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2), zlim=c(-2,2))

segments3d(c(-2-0.2,2-0.2), c(0,0), c(0,0), col="black", lwd=3)
segments3d(c(0,0), c(-2-0.2,2-0.2), c(0,0), col="black", lwd=3)
segments3d(c(0,0), c(0,0), c(-2-0.2,2-0.2), col="black", lwd=3)
text3d(matrix(c(2,0,0, 0,2,0, 0,0,2),ncol=3),texts=c('x+', 'y+', 'z+'))         

# semi-transparent planes on xy, xz, and yz planes
rect3Drgl(x0 = 0, y0 = -2, z0 = -2, x1 = NULL, y1 = 2, z1 = 2, 
    lwd=1, col="#0000ff", alpha=0.1, add=TRUE) #yz
rect3Drgl(x0 = -2, y0 = 0, z0 = -2, x1 = 2, y1 = NULL, z1 = 2, 
    lwd=1, col="#ff0000", alpha=0.1, add=TRUE) #xz
rect3Drgl(x0 = -2, y0 = -2, z0 = 0, x1 = 2, y1 = 2, z1 = NULL, 
    lwd=1, col="#00ff00", alpha=0.1, add=TRUE) #xy
```

If I run the script as-is, I get this error for each call to `rect3Drgl()`:

> Error in cbind(as.vector(x), as.vector(y), as.vector(z), 1) %*% plist$mat :
>     requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

BUT, if I run this first and then close the new graphics window...

```
rect3Drgl(x0 = -2, y0 = -2, z0 = 0, x1 = 2, y1 = 2, z1 = NULL, 
    lwd=1, col="#00ff00", alpha=0.1) # remove add=TRUE
```

NOW I can run those three `rect3Drgl(...)` statements and get my lovely plot:

[image: Plot with semitransparent xy,xz,yz planes]

Why did I have to run `rect3Drgl()` without add=TRUE to get my plot to work with add=TRUE?

Comment: I haven't debugged it, but I would guess that `rect3Drgl` without `add = TRUE` saves some context information, so that when you call it with `add = TRUE` it knows what to do.  Note that `rect3Drgl` is not an `rgl` function, it's in the `plot3Drgl` package, while `plot3d` is in the `rgl` package.  It's not surprising that mixing calls gives strange results.  There's a `plot3D` function in `plot3Drgl`; it would likely be the thing to call to set up your `plot3Drgl` context.

Comment: parse `rgltype = 'add'` to `rect3Drgl` will give desire output.

Comment: @user2554330 - `plot3Drgl` sounds promising, but even after running `library(plot3Drgl)`, I get the error "could not find function 'plot3Drgl'"  Any suggestions?

Comment: The function is `plot3D`, not `plot3Drgl`.